# Dividing by x on two sides of an equation is not always the same equation??

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$y = p*x$

$\frac{y}{x} = \frac{p*x}{x}$

These equations are 'equal' via common math principles.

If $x = 0$, then in the first equation $y = 0$. In the second equation,
its not defined (since you are diving by zero) no?

Whats going on here? Are those two equations truly equal?

Comment: We usually define "division" the following way: **if $x\neq 0$, there exists a unique $x^{-1}$ such that $xx^{-1}=1$**, part of the definition requires that the number that you want to divide by is different from $0$.

Comment: It's as you say: if the second is true (which must mean x is not 0), the first is true (this is called "B implies A"); and if the first is true, x could be zero, so A does not imply B (only for x not zero it does). Two equations are "equal" is called they are "equivalent", which is the same as saying either one implies the other. As this is not true here, they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

These equations aren't truly equal in the sense that you're talking about. The reason is that in order to go from $y=px$ to $\frac yx = \frac{px}x$, we have to make the assumption that $x \ne 0$ and the latter equation only makes sense when $x \ne 0$ as you've said.

In short the equations are equivalent *where they are defined* but the latter equation isn't defined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is zero, then dividing by it will not yield a meaningful result. It is not a valid mathematical operation.

If $x$ is not zero then indeed $y/x = p$.